# How do I create Async code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord.js

Hey so im making a leaderboard for a discord bot using `discord.js` And I want to display users by their names instead of their ID's so using `discord.js` I use the function `.fetchUser(ID)`

`.fetchUser(ID)` is a promise which can take a some of time depending on the bandwidth.

So because `discord.js` uses a promise my code is no longer Async, I *thought* that by putting the code in a promise it would run Async.

And I was wrong.

**my code:**

```
//This is ran inside a .prototype function so (this) is defined
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.list = [];
    //users is an object with user's IDs as the key
    //Currently it only has one key in it (mine)
    for (let i in users) {
            let pos = 0;
            let score = this.getScore(users[i]);
            if (score === 0) {
                client.fetchUser(i).then((user)=> {
                    console.log(`pushed`);//logs way after the "finish" is logged 
                    this.list.push([user.username.substring(0,13), score])
                });
                continue;
            }
            for (let h = 0; h < this.list.length; h++) {
                if (score >= this.list[h][1]) {
                    pos = h;
                    break;
                }
            }
            client.fetchUser(users[i].id).then((user) => {
                this.list.splice(pos, 0, [user.username.substring(0,13), score])
            })
        }
        console.log(`Finished: `+this.list.length);
        resolve(this.list);
})
```

Comment: you need to chain your promises.

Comment: Look into the function "Promise.all" to take a list of promises (eg, `var onepromise = client.fetchUser(i);` - add them to a list), and create a single promise that will churn out a list of response values. You probably don't need to explicitly use `new Promise` for your use case.

Comment: *"because discord.js uses a promise my code is no longer Async"* quite the opposite.  Your code **is** async because promises are involved.

Comment: Please show this whole class.  What does `getScore()` look like?  Does it return a promise?  Also where does `users` come from?

Comment: @zero298 i am new to promises all i know at the moment is, because there is a promise. . . my code doesnt work.
and you dont wanna see the whole class... it's quite lengthy,
But `getScore()` returns a number

Comment: Just to clarify, does it return a `Number`, or a `Promise` that will resolve to a `Number`?

Comment: just a `number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to chain off of `Promise`s you receive.  [`Client#fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) returns a `Promise` which you *are* waiting on, but not enough.  You have to propagate up `Promise`s.  If something in your function call chain is asynchronous, you should consider the whole chain async.

You fill `this.list` from within the `fetchUser(...).then(...)`, which isn't necessarily bad, as long as you don't try to use `list` until after `fetchUser`'s resolution chain is done.  You aren't doing that; you immediately `resolve(this.list)`.

Consider this abbreviated form of your original function:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.list = [];
    for (let i in users) {
        // A promise is created right here
        client.fetchUser(i).then((user) => {
            // This will populate list AFTER the then callback
            this.list.push([user.username.substring(0, 13), score])
        });
    }
    // You aren't waiting until the promise created by fetchUser completes
    resolve(this.list);
})
```

`this.list` can't be considered "complete" until all the users involved have had their profiles loaded and their scores retrieved.  Considering that, we can use `Promise.all()` which takes an array of `Promise`s and then resolves once all of the provided promises have resolved.  So to wait that way, we would do something like this, which still isn't ideal, but waits correctly:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.list = [];

    // This is an array of Promises
    const discordUsersPromise = users.map(user => client.fetchUser(user));

    // Wait till all the fetchUser calls are done
    const listIsPopulatedPromise = Promise.all(discordUsersPromise).then(dUsers => {
        // This replaces your for (let i in users) {}
        Object.entries(users).forEach((user, idx) => {
            const score = this.getScore(user);
            const discordUser = dUsers[idx];
            this.list.push([discordUser.username.substring(0, 13), score])
        });
    });

    // We still have to wait for the list to be completely populated
    return listIsPopulatedPromise.then(() => this.list);
})
```

---

Consider this implementation.  I have made some assumptions about your code since you use `this.list` but don't include what `this` is an instance of, but most of it should be the same:

```
/**
 * Object to composite certain user properties
 * @typedef {RealUser}
 * @property {String} user The local string for the user
 * @property {User} realUser The user that Discord gives us
 * @property {Number} score The score this user has
 */

/**
 * Class to encapsulate user and score and data
 */
class Game {
    /**
     * Constructs a game
     */
    constructor() {
        /**
         * The users we are keeping score of
         * @type {Object}
         */
        this.users = {};
    }
    /**
     * Get the score of a particular user
     * @param {String} user User to get score of
     * @returns {Number} User's score
     */
    getScore(user) {
        return this.users[user] || 0;
    }
    /**
     * Get a composite of users and their status
     * @param {String[]} users The users to put on our leaderboard
     * @returns {Promise<RealUser[]>} Sorted list of users that we included in our leaderboard
     */
    getLeaderBoard(users) {
        // Map all the users that we are given to Promises returned bye fetchUser()
        const allRealUsersPromise = Promise.all(users.map(user => client.fetchUser(user)
            /*
             * Create an object that will composite the string that we use
             * to note the user locally, the Discord User Object, and the
             * current score of the user that we are tracking locally
             */
            .then(realUser => ({
                user,
                realUser,
                score: this.getScore(user)
            }))));

        /*
         * Once we have all the data we need to construct a leaderboard,
         * we should sort the users by score, and hand back an array
         * of RealUsers which should contain all the data we want to
         * print a leaderboard
         */
        return allRealUsersPromise
            .then(scoredUsers => scoredUsers.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score));
    }
    /**
     * Prints out a leaderboard
     * @param {String[]} users The users to include on our leaderboard
     */
    printLeaderBoard(users) {
        // Go get a leaderboard to print
        this.getLeaderBoard(users).then(sortedScoredUsers => {
            // Iterate our RealUsers
            sortedScoredUsers.forEach((sortedScoredUser, idx) => {
                const username = sortedScoredUser.realUser.username;
                const score = sortedScoredUser.score;
                // Print out their status
                console.log(`${username.substring(0, 13)} is in position ${idx + 1} with ${score} points`);
            });
        });
    }
}

const game = new Game();
game.users["bob"] = 5;
game.users["sue"] = 7;
game.users["tim"] = 3;

game.printLeaderBoard(Object.keys(game.users));
```